# GUID in an EXE binary

Tags: c++, encoding, binary, bit-manipulation, guid

I am compiling a .exe from C++ code. This code contains a GUID (structure defined in guiddef.h):

```
GUID test = { 0x4d1e55b2, 0xf16f, 0x11cf, 0x88, 0xcb, 0x00, 0x12, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12 };
```

Now if I convert my .exe file contents to a hexadecimal string, I would expect to find those hexadecimal numbers. But I don't. I do find my hard coded strings (encoded as ASCII). So where is my GUID gone? Is it encoded with different byte ordering, so I don't find it as shown above?

Comment: Do you actually utilize this `test` variable (inside of executable) somehow? If you don't it might be just thrown away.

Comment: Try disabling optimizations or declare it volatile, and see if it appears

Comment: byte ordering could certainly be relevant, depending for which target processor you are compiling.

Comment: Use a easily-spottable, byte-order independent GUID, like a one which has only byte 0x77 in it to check its presence in the exe

Comment: @AllanNørgaard I tried declaring it volatile and use it in a "if" statement but it doesn't seem to change

Comment: @geza I used a more spottable value like 0x7777777777 and I turned to debug config (no optimization) and it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's byte swapped, within the single components of the struct.

E.g. for your string you would search (spacing added for explanatory purposes): `b2551e4d 6ff1 cf11 88 cb 00 12 12 00 00 12`.